# HTML / Wordpress image height / width issues

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm working on getting images to resize depending on the clients browser (desktop vs mobile).

I've put in place max-width:100%, images are formatted identically, 900x900 px, but some of them overstretch the width and some don't.

Examples of this are (in mobile);

- https://nottinghamshirefireworks.co.uk/product/rainbow-strobe/ - This works fine
- https://nottinghamshirefireworks.co.uk/product/rainbow-colour-wheels-2-pack/ - This doesn't

Its a wordpress site and its setting the width explicitly in HTML, which I believe is causing the problem.

My question is will the CSS width / height override the HTML property settings? And if not, how does one stop Wordpress setting the HTML properties for width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme has a weird setting that adds width property to each product. It was different for the products you mentioned.

I limited the width of the div by adding `max-width:100vw` for this class `woocommerce-product-gallery__image`, which seems to do the job but you need to find out why different inline width properties are added to different products even though they have same 900x900 image sizes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ozgur, good shout, I was inspecting the element but the hover over was reporting the image size and I hadn't checked the element style in the developer pane.

Comment: Your welcome @CarlBruiners. I tried to solve the extra space below the image issue but couldn't find the source of it by just using the developer pane.

Comment: Thanks @ozgur, I have had better sucess with a load of white space removal, the theme isn't the well put together, so its hacks (a few overrides with !important) which is less than ideal.

Comment: Its if there's a second image on the gallery, thats what causes the extra white space.